# how to use Retrofit2 @POST

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have to get Data from this URL  https://openweathermap.org/.

Now i am working with these API

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=(cityname)&appid=(myAPIKEY)

So I've already this code below to work

[image: Click to see my code]

This is my base URL:

> Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
```

Does anyone know how to pass cityName as a Parameter?

Ps. Retrofit2

Comment: Please state your error, and also I would like to see your BASE_URL ? Looks like you are making a request to `weatherq=(cityname)&appid=(myAPIKEY)`. You should use the full path there !

Comment: Sorry.
this is my base url.

Comment: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

Comment: replace `POST` with `GET`.

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: Have you tried `Syed Sumair`'s answer? If so what issues are you having?

Comment: Yes,I have tried. But it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **@Query** parameter to provide any parameter like

```
@GET("weather")
Call<WeatherEnt> getWeatherData(@Query("q") String query,
                                @Query("units") String units,
                                @Query("appid") String appid);
```

and pass cityName and other values (as if you're required) in these parameter when calling this end point

Comment: where you're facing the problem, specify

Comment: you can use this method like `weatherInterfaceObj.loadPhotoList("london","metric","YOUR_APP_ID")`

Comment: It's working!!!!. Thank you Sir. It need just 2 pameters
@GET("weather")
    Call<Example> loadPhotoList(@Query("q") String cityName,@Query("appid") String appid);

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change your second method like this :

```
@POST("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq={cityName}&appid=1273091827310988273")
Call<Example> loadPhotoList(@Path("cityName") String cityName);
```

Comment: I have to use BASE_URL. So this full URL will not working

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone.
This is an answer.

> @GET("weather")
>       Call loadPhotoList(@Query("q") String cityName,@Query("appid") String appid);